# USB rs232 UART connection issue

Tags: dmesg

i connect my board to my laptop with rs232 usb adapter.
lsusb i see that my port is well attached to ttyUSB[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwgjs.png)
but i can't access to my board ni by minicom neither putty nor screen
someone here can help me please.

Comment: You need to describe what you have with a lot more detail.  *"USB rs232 UART"* is really a contradiction.  The USB adapter will be either for RS-232 voltages or UART TTL voltages (and there's two possible choices for TTL voltages).  Does this USB adapter have matching voltages with your board?

Comment: i want to say rs232 used as uart connection ( i use rs232 tx, rx, gnd pins )